# Função com quantidade variável de parâmetros, qual melhor maneira de fazer?

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de fazer uma função sem definir a quantidade de parâmetros necessários. Quais as maneiras ou alternativas que posso utilizar para obter esse resultado?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pode usar o .call() ou o .aplly ou mesmo chamar a função da forma mais convecional, e dentro da função, usar a palavra reservada `arguments`

```
function foo() {
    console.log(this, arguments);
}
foo.call('foo', 1, {animal: 'cão'}, 3)
foo.apply('foo', [1, {animal: 'cão'}, 3])
foo('foo', 1, {animal: 'cão'}, 3, 4);
```

#### http://jsfiddle.net/NDZeV/

Estas 3 maneiras diferentes de chamar uma função e passar argumentos dão o mesmo resultado nos dois primeiros casos.

```
'foo', // usando o call() e o apply() o primeiro argumento é o this
Arguments[3] // aqui o arguments têm em forma tipo array os restantes argumentos
    0: 1                // o mesmo que arguments[0], ou seja 1
    1: {animal: 'cão'}  // o mesmo que arguments[1], ou seja {animal: 'cão'} 
    2: 3                // o mesmo que arguments[2], ou seja 3
```

No caso do ultimo exemplo, chamando a função diretamente o `this` é relativo ao escopo em que se está, provavelmente `window` e não tem a ver com os parametros passados à função. Neste caso o àrguments`tem somente valores passados da forma mais comum ou seja`func(a, b, c)`. Neste exemplo de código acima isso dá:

```
window, // aqui o "this" nõ tem a ver com os parametros da função e vai buscar o valor do this no escopo em que a função estiver
Arguments[3] // argumentos
    0: 'foo'            // o mesmo que arguments[0], ou seja 'foo'
    1:                  // o mesmo que arguments[1], ou seja 1
    2: {animal: 'cão'}  // o mesmo que arguments[2], ou seja {animal: 'cão'} 
    3: 4                // o mesmo que arguments[3], ou seja 3
    4: 4                // o mesmo que arguments[4], ou seja 4
```

Este objeto `arguments` é uma variável local da função e não é um array mas sim como o @bfavaretto indicou é um *array-like object*, e partilhar por exemplo a  propriedade `length` das arrays.

**MDN:**

- [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments)
- [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
- [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: Se eu chamar a função foo(numero), onde int numero = 10; Como dar um alert dessa variavel dentro da função?

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto. Só mais uma pergunta. Se eu quiser dar um alert que mostre o nome da variável, como ficaria?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo como assim, o que quer dizer com "o nome da variável"?

Comment: @bfavaretto tens toda a razão. Vou corrigir...

Comment: Se eu chamar foo(numero, letra) e quiser mostrar na tela a string "numero" e "letra", ou seja, o nome das variaveis que passei como parametro.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, para ter nomes têm de usar objectos, aí tem de usar `Object.keys(numero);`, se quiser saber que tipo de variável é tem de usar o `typeof`. Pode especificar melhor qual deles procura?

Comment: O meu objetivo final é fazer uma função que crie uma string montando um objeto Json. quando eu chamasse foo(numero, letra); ai ficaria assim: "{ 'numero': '1', 'letra' :'A' }"; Por isso, gostaria de extrair o nome da variavel.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Não dá para extrair os nomes dos parâmetros da função. Quer dizer, até dá, mas é uma baita gambiarra. Agora, o que você queria não era justamente passar qualquer quantidade de parâmetros? Nesse caso você não usaria parâmetros nomeados, certo?

Comment: Uso parametros nomeados. Tem ajax em toda aplicacao e sempre tenho que criar a string data com os parametros e valores para enviar ao Controller C#. Ai gostaria de montar essa função para simplificar.

Answer (score 8):

A resposta do Sergio é excelente e concordo que seja a correta. Vou deixar uma alternativa apenas para aumentar o leque de opções para quem quiser trabalhar com múltiplos parâmetros.

Existe uma técnica que é receber um único parâmetro - um dicionário de opções. Essa técnica é utilizada em frameworks como o *jQuery*, [por exemplo](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-options).

Um exemplo:

```
function AplicaCSS (options) {
    if (!options) return;
    var font = options.font || "arial 12";
    var height = options.height || "15px";
    var width = options.width || "100px";
    /*etc., etc.*/
}
```

Note que, dessa forma, você simplesmente passa um objeto cujas propriedades podem variar. Se eu chamar a função dessa forma:

```
AplicaCSS({font: "comic sans bold"});
```

... Funciona. Do jeito que a função está, as propriedades "faltantes" recebem valores padrão. Se eu chamar a função da seguinte forma:

```
AplicaCSS({height: "10px", width: "50px"});
```

... Ou:

```
AplicaCSS({});
```

... Ou mesmo:

```
AplicaCSS({bar: "lolwut"}); // Como é uma propriedade que não espero, 'bar' é ignorada.
```

... Funciona do mesmo jeito. Assim, a quantidade de parâmetros variáveis é do objeto que você passa, não da função em si. Isso lhe dá muita flexibilidade, além de você ter uma função com assinatura fixa e conhecida. Vale a pena também documentar as propriedades que você procura no objeto recebido, para quem for usar sua função ;)

Answer (score 1):

você pode utilizar um array para os parametros ou seja não sendo necessário defini-los.

cria uma regra para tratar dinamicamente estes valores e resolveu seu problema.

Utilizo muito isso

Comment: Você podia acrescentar um exemplo a sua resposta.